# collision detection on more than 2 divs with jQuery draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, collision-detection

Here is a fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/dh4qysej/

I'm looking to do this with dynamically created elements, so the divs may not actually exist yet when the function is called.

I would like to try work out a solution which could cover x amount of divs and handle it with minimal code, but making a scrappy version to accommodate three divs seems to be the logical first step before figuring out a way to cover even more.

I figured I would have to put if - else if statements in order to detect calculations across all the variables, however it doesn't seem to work. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance - code below (working between first two divs);

```js
function collision($div1, $div2, $div3) {
  if ($div1.length > 0) {
    var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
    var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
    var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
    var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
    var b1 = y1 + h1;
    var r1 = x1 + w1;
  }

  if ($div2.length > 0) {
    var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
    var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
    var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
    var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
    var b2 = y2 + h2;
    var r2 = x2 + w2;
  }

  if ($div3.length > 0) {
    var x3 = $div3.offset().left;
    var y3 = $div3.offset().top;
    var h3 = $div3.outerHeight(true);
    var w3 = $div3.outerWidth(true);
    var b3 = y3 + h3;
    var r3 = x3 + w3;
  }

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}


onmousemove = function(e) {
  $('#result').text(collision($('#div1'), $('#div2'), $("#div3")));
};


$('#div1,#div2, #div3').draggable();
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#div2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
#div3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<strong>Drag divs around.</strong>

<div id="div1">
  Div1
</div>
<br/>
<div id="div2">
  Div2
</div>
<br>
<div id="div3">
  Div3
</div>

<p>Colliding? <span id="result">false</span>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firstly instead of using id to bind events use class selector.
2. Use a flag to check if user is currently dragging any of the draggable item.
3. Loop through all draggable items and test collision with respect to the current dragged element.

```js
function collision(draggableItems) {
  return draggableItems
     .toArray()
    .reduce(function(isColliding, currNode){
        if(isColliding){return isColliding;}
        var $currNode = $(currNode);
        var x1 = $currNode.offset().left;
        var y1 = $currNode.offset().top;
        var h1 = $currNode.outerHeight(true);
        var w1 = $currNode.outerWidth(true);
        var b1 = y1 + h1;
        var r1 = x1 + w1;
        draggableItems.each(function(index, node){
          if(node == currNode || isColliding){
            return;
          }
          var $node = $(node);
          var x2 = $node.offset().left;
          var y2 = $node.offset().top;
          var h2 = $node.outerHeight(true);
          var w2 = $node.outerWidth(true);
          var b2 = y2 + h1;
          var r2 = x2 + w1;
                
          if(!(b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2)){
            isColliding = true;
          }
        });
        return isColliding;
  }, false);
}


    var isDragging = false;

    $('.draggableItem')
      .on('mousedown', function(e){
        isDragging = true;
      })
      .on('mousemove',function(e) {
        if(!isDragging){return;}
        $('#result').text(collision($('.draggableItem')));
      })
      .on('mouseup', function(e){
        isDragging = false;
      });

    $('.draggableItem').draggable();
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#div2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
#div3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<strong>Drag divs around.</strong>

<div id="div1" class="draggableItem">
  Div1
</div>
<br/>
<div id="div2" class="draggableItem">
  Div2
</div>
<br>
<div id="div3" class="draggableItem">
  Div3
</div>

<p>Colliding? <span id="result">false</span>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: good solution. But there is a bug. drag div1 to div2. now colliding to true. and just drag div3 but dont touch to other divs. Now it will false.

Comment: Not working. same issue is there. Now you are checking only the dragging div. you should check other divs also.

Comment: Sorry about that. i have really fixed it this time :)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks